# How to get a whole number from a list?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list:

```
num = ['9', '9', '2', '3']
```

So, how do i get a number 9923, for example in a variable?

Comment: int(''.join(num))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = ''.join(num)
n = int(n)
print(n)
```

output will be 9923

Answer (score 4):

```py
num = ['9','9','2','3']

new_num = ''.join(num)

try:
    new_num = int(new_num)
except ValueError as e:
    print("Not a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base-10 expansion.

```
num = ['9','9','2','3']

decimal_num = sum(int(c)*10**i for i, c in zip(range(len(num)-1, -1, -1), num))
```

or maybe in more readable way

```
decimal_num = sum(int(c)*10**(len(num)-i-1) for i, c in enumerate(num))
```